# Having difficulty with pstricks box plot, psaxes, pspicture

Tags: pstricks, boxplot

a TeX noob here. I wish to plot performance test results once every two weeks (or sooner) displaying a 2 week window. I saw a similar question:
[Can I use pgfplots to make a boxplot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3983/can-i-use-pgfplots-to-make-a-boxplot/22619#comment115112_22619)

and the following answer looks very appealing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(12,14)
\psset{yunit=0.1,fillstyle=solid}
\psaxes[dy=1cm,Dy=10,ticksize=4pt 0,axesstyle=frame](0,0)(12,130)
\rput(1,0){\psBoxplot[fillcolor=red!30]{
   100 90 120 115 120 110 100 110 100 90 100 100 120 120 120}}\rput(1,105){2001}
\rput(3,0){\psBoxplot[arrowlength=0.5,fillcolor=blue!30]{
  90 120 115 116 115 110 90 130 120 120 120 85 100 130 130}}\rput(3,107){2008}
\rput(5,0){\psBoxplot[barwidth=40pt,arrowlength=1.2,fillcolor=red!30]{
  35 70 90 60 100 60 60 80 80 60 50 55 90 70 70}}\rput(5,65){2001}
\rput(7,0){\psBoxplot[barwidth=40pt,fillcolor=blue!30]{
  60 65 60 75 75 60 50 90 95 60 65 45 45 60 90}}\rput(7,65){2008}
\rput(9,0){\psBoxplot[fillcolor=red!30]{
  20 20 25 20 15 20 20 25 30 20 20 20 30 30 30}}\rput(9,22){2001}
\rput(11,0){\psBoxplot[fillcolor=blue!30,linestyle=dashed]{
  20 30 20 35 35 20 20 60 50 20 35 15 30 20 40}}\rput(11,25){2008}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

except that it does not quite do what I want it to do. I have obviously tried to modify this example to produce what I want, but I have been so unsuccessful, that I do not have anything else to share, since it won't help a bit. My attempts to re-adjust the coordinates (say to bound a rectangle at left bottom point (12, 40) and right upper point (27,45)) just would not do what I want it to do. They would still start at 0, or would show nothing or garbage. I did not feel like I can change one or two things and get closer to my goal. Too many settings that can potentially conflict, perhaps ... Below is a sample picture that I would like to generate (I drew it manually using Dia). The box plots in my picture all look the same only because it was simpler to copy and paste them. In reality they will be generated with three real numbers - run 1, run 2 and run 3 in minutes, for example: 42.456, 44.123, 43.854. Occasionally a test will not run correctly and I will need to display an error. I would highly appreciate if you could provide me with code that can generate something that looks like the picture below.

[image]

UPDATE: This worked with MikTeX 2.9 but not MikTeX 2.8 under Windows.

UPDATE2: Set `Oy=4` if you want to raise the plot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**

I recommend the environment `psgraph` provided by the package `pst-plot`. In this way you can simple adjust the graph.

I build an example which produces a basis and hope it helps.

First the result ;-)

[image]

To simplify the work I created three new commands. The first one `\weekday` provided the day of the week whereby 1 represent `Monday`. In this way the labels of the axis are done.

The next two commands draw the rectangles. The command `\simpleframe` has the following syntax:

```
\simpleframe[options] 
            ( coordinates of lower left corner )
            ( coordinates of upper right corner )
            {text inside the frame}
```

The second new command is `\complexframe` which has the following syntax.

```
\complexframe[global options] 
             ( coordinates of lower left corner )
             ( coordinates of upper right corner )
             [options for the first line]
             {y value of the first line}
             [options for the second line]
             {y value of the second line}
             {text}
```

The default values are shown in the image.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{xparse}
\newcount\daycount
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\DeclareDocumentCommand \weekday { m }
{
\prg_case_int:nnn 
    {  \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 7 }   }
   { 
     { 1 } {Mo}
     { 2 } {Tue}
     { 3 } {Wed}
     { 4 } {Thu}
     { 5 } {Fri}
     { 6 } {Sat}
     { 0 } {Son}
   }
  {error}
%}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\NewDocumentCommand \simpleframe { O{linecolor=black,linewidth=1pt,fillcolor=red!70,fillstyle=solid} r() r() m }
{
 \begingroup
  \psset{#1}
  \pst@getcoor{#2}\pst@tempA
  \pst@getcoor{#3}\pst@tempB
  \psframe(!%
      \pst@tempA /YA exch \pst@number\psyunit div def
                                /XA exch \pst@number\psxunit div def
      XA YA
      )(!
      \pst@tempB /YB exch \pst@number\psyunit div def
                                /XB exch \pst@number\psxunit div def
      XB YB
      )
   \rput(!%
      \pst@tempA /YA exch \pst@number\psyunit div def
                                /XA exch \pst@number\psxunit div def
      \pst@tempB /YB exch \pst@number\psyunit div def
                                /XB exch \pst@number\psxunit div def
      XA XB add 2 div
      YA  YB add 2 div
      ){#4}
 \endgroup
}

\NewDocumentCommand \complexframe { %
          O{linecolor=black,linewidth=1pt,fillcolor=red!20,fillstyle=solid}% default option 
          r() r() %coordinates of the frame
          O{linecolor=blue,linewidth=2pt} m  %y-value of the first line+option
          O{linecolor=yellow,linewidth=2pt,linestyle=dashed} m % y-value of the second line+option
          m %Text 
 }
{
 \begingroup
  \psset{#1}
  \pst@getcoor{#2}\pst@tempA
  \pst@getcoor{#3}\pst@tempB
  \psframe(!%global frame
      \pst@tempA /YA exch \pst@number\psyunit div def
                                /XA exch \pst@number\psxunit div def
      XA YA
      )(!
      \pst@tempB /YB exch \pst@number\psyunit div def
                                /XB exch \pst@number\psxunit div def
      XB YB
      )
   \rput(!%text
      \pst@tempA /YA exch \pst@number\psyunit div def
                                /XA exch \pst@number\psxunit div def
      \pst@tempB /YB exch \pst@number\psyunit div def
                                /XB exch \pst@number\psxunit div def
      XA XB add 2 div
      YA  YB add 2 div
      ){#8}
  \begingroup
    \psset{#4}
       \pst@getcoor{0,#5}\pst@tempC
    \psline (!%first line
      \pst@tempA /YA exch \pst@number\psyunit div def
                                /XA exch \pst@number\psxunit div def
      \pst@tempC /YC exch \pst@number\psyunit div def
                                /XC exch \pst@number\psxunit div def
        XA  YC)(!%
      \pst@tempB /YB exch \pst@number\psyunit div def
                                /XB exch \pst@number\psxunit div def
      \pst@tempC /YC exch \pst@number\psyunit div def
                                /XC exch \pst@number\psxunit div def
         XB YC )
  \endgroup
  \begingroup
    \psset{#6}
       \pst@getcoor{0,#7}\pst@tempC
    \psline (!%first line
      \pst@tempA /YA exch \pst@number\psyunit div def
                                /XA exch \pst@number\psxunit div def
      \pst@tempC /YC exch \pst@number\psyunit div def
                                /XC exch \pst@number\psxunit div def
        XA  YC)(!%
      \pst@tempB /YB exch \pst@number\psyunit div def
                                /XB exch \pst@number\psxunit div def
      \pst@tempC /YC exch \pst@number\psyunit div def
                                /XC exch \pst@number\psxunit div def
         XB YC )
  \endgroup
  \psframe[fillstyle=none](!%global frame again
      \pst@tempA /YA exch \pst@number\psyunit div def
                                /XA exch \pst@number\psxunit div def
      XA YA
      )(!
      \pst@tempB /YB exch \pst@number\psyunit div def
                                /XB exch \pst@number\psxunit div def
      XB YB
      )
 \endgroup
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}
\psset{%
xAxisLabel={Day}, yAxisLabel={Whatever},
xAxisLabelPos={16,-15pt},yAxisLabelPos={-0.4in,c},
}

\begin{psgraph}[,Oy=0,labels=y]{->}(0,0)(16,21){0.8\linewidth}{10cm}
\psframe(0,0)(15,20.5)
\multido{\iA=1+1,\iB=14+1}{14}{%
 \psxTick(\iA){\weekday{\iA}}%
 \psxTick[labelsep=20pt](\iA){\iB}%
}

\simpleframe(3,3)(4,6){foo}


\complexframe(10,10)(12,20){14}{18}{foobar}

\end{psgraph}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very cool! Final touch - what f I wanted to draw my own box? Since I only have 3 values and their average, it would not make sense for me to have the 25th and the 75th percentile. I would want the similar look and feel though - a colored rectangle with two lines in the middle and text.

Comment: @TheDude: Do I understand it correct that you simple need a rectangle at a special position with some text?

Comment: That for the error (in red) plus a rectangle with two lines going across it in the middle of different color. Case 1: red rectangle from (3,3) to (4, 6) with text inside of it. Case 2: pink rectangle from (10, 10) to (12, 20) with some text inside of it, and also a line from (10, 14) to (12, 14) of the same color and thickness as the border plus another line from (10, 18) to (12, 18) of different color, dashed, and of different thickness. I will stop bugging you after that, I swear.

Comment: @TheDude: I edited my example.

Comment: Thanks! Can you recommend some documents to go through so that I can understand some of that pstricks macro magic? Whatever is between `\begin{document}' and `\end{document}` is pretty readable to me. I'd like to find a document or two that would clue me in on syntax and details of the rest of what you did, so that I could modify the behavior of the macros/defs myself.

Comment: @TheDude: First of all the command definition is explained in the documentation of `xparse`. The rest is well explained in the book PSTricks.

Comment: @TheDude: I have no Windows and I am working with TeX Live. Did you try MikTeX 2.9 or TeX Live?

Comment: Why do you think MikTeX 2.9 isn't stable. This is the current stable release ;-). However avoiding `xparse` make the live more complicate. I know way but it's really ugly ;-)

Comment: This worked with MikTex 2.9 - I am deleting my earlier complaints.

Comment: @TheDude: What do you expect?

Comment: @TheDude: Did you try Oy=16?