# How to single label a point in pgfplots with text?

Tags: pgfplots

This seems like it should be straightforward but I'm new to using pgfplots. I have been using [this awesome box plot code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84544/20940) and would like to be able to add a single point

How can I make:

```
\addplot[color = black, mark = *, nodes near coords,every node near coord/.style={anchor=180}]coordinates {( 0, -1)};
```

Label with a text label (say `mylabel`) rather than the value (-1) which is displayed?

The total code is (combined with box plotting code):

```
\begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat}
%x whiskerbottom boxbottom median boxtop whiskertop 
 0  -0.573413   -0.528268   -0.641948 -0.483655 -0.794368   
\end{filecontents}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [
    xtick={0},
    xticklabels=test, 
    box plot width=10mm]

\boxplot [black]{testdata.dat}
%I've modified things to get to this point but cannot seem to figure out how to add a text label to it
\addplot[color = black, mark = *, nodes near coords,every node near coord/.style={anchor=180}]coordinates {( 0, -1)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Could you please expand your code to a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)? Simply adding a documentclass and the tikz and pgfplots package didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can set the contents of the nodes by using the optional argument to `node near coords=<content>`. By default, it's set to `\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}`, but you can use any text or code. To use the static text `mylabel`, you'd say `nodes near coords=mylabel`:

```
\addplot [black, mark = *, nodes near coords=mylabel,every node near coord/.style={anchor=180}] coordinates {( 0, -1)};
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add a single point based on a predefined function but couldn't find an appropriate answer among this question and related questions.

Therefore, for future reference, if you have your own function defined as e.g.:

```
\begin[tikzpicture][declare function={y(\x) = \x^2;}] ...
```

And you want to add a single point based on this function, you should use:

```
\addplot [only marks,samples at={5}] {y(x)};
```

That's the best way to add a single point to an existing function, regardless of your `axis` setup or of other functions that have been added to the plot.

Hope this might help someone out in the future.