# How can I setup my data so I can create pgfplots boxplots and update the x-indices for multiple series?

Tags: pgfplots

I have been using [this box plot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84544/20940) code to great effect recently. I am making a large amount of plots in my thesis and would like to be able to do the following data format:

```
\begin{filecontents}{dataOne.dat}
%x whiskerbottom boxbottom median boxtop whiskertop 
 0  -0.573413   -0.528268   -0.641948 -0.483655 -0.794368   
 1  -0.673413   -0.628268   -0.741948 -0.583655 -0.894368       
\end{filecontents}
```

etc.

This is how `\boxplot` is defined:

```
\newcommand{\boxplot}[2][]{
    \addplot [box plot median,#1] table {#2};
    \addplot [forget plot, box plot box,#1] table {#2};
    \addplot [forget plot, box plot top whisker,#1] table {#2};
    \addplot [forget plot, box plot bottom whisker,#1] table {#2};
}
```

I am adding these to my plot using:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [xtick={0,1},  xmin=-1,  xmax =2,  xticklabels={test,test2},   box plot width=5mm]
\boxplot [black, forget plot]{dataOne.dat}
\addplot[color = black, mark = *, nodes near coords,every node near coord/.style={anchor=180}]coordinates {( 0, -1)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

---

How can I use the `\boxplot` command to let me specify to ONLY use a specific row of the table, ie something like:

```
\boxplot [black, forget plot]{dataOne.dat,0}  %only use row 0
\boxplot [black, forget plot]{dataOne.dat}  % use entire datafile
```

so it would ONLY reference the first data row in dataOne.dat if passed. Otherwise I have to create separate datafiles to view just one or both box plots.

I know I need to modify:

```
table{#2}
```

to have some sort of conditional argument which is passed through the `\boxplot` creation, but I'm not really sure how to do this. The [documentation here](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplotstable.pdf) is way over my head and seems to focus exclusively on retrieving specific values for a specified column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `x filter/.code` that checks whether the current `\coordindex` is equal to the desired row number, and if it's not, discard the coordinate:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{dataOne.dat}
%x whiskerbottom boxbottom median boxtop whiskertop 
 0  -0.573413   -0.528268   -0.641948 -0.483655 -0.794368   
 1  -0.673413   -0.628268   -0.741948 -0.583655 -0.894368       
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotsset{
    box plot/.style={
        /pgfplots/.cd,
        black,
        only marks,
        mark=-,
        mark size=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/box plot width},
        /pgfplots/error bars/y dir=plus,
        /pgfplots/error bars/y explicit,
        /pgfplots/table/x index=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/box plot x index},
    },
    box plot box/.style={
        /pgfplots/error bars/draw error bar/.code 2 args={%
            \draw  ##1 -- ++(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/box plot width},0pt) |- ##2 -- ++(-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/box plot width},0pt) |- ##1 -- cycle;
        },
        /pgfplots/table/.cd,
        y index=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/box plot box top index},
        y error expr={
            \thisrowno{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/box plot box bottom index}}
            - \thisrowno{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/box plot box top index}}
        },
        /pgfplots/box plot
    },
    box plot top whisker/.style={
        /pgfplots/error bars/draw error bar/.code 2 args={%
            \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/error bars/error mark}%
            {\pgfplotserrorbarsmark}%
            \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/error bars/error mark options}%
            {\pgfplotserrorbarsmarkopts}%
            \path ##1 -- ##2;
        },
        /pgfplots/table/.cd,
        y index=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/box plot whisker top index},
        y error expr={
            \thisrowno{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/box plot box top index}}
            - \thisrowno{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/box plot whisker top index}}
        },
        /pgfplots/box plot
    },
    box plot bottom whisker/.style={
        /pgfplots/error bars/draw error bar/.code 2 args={%
            \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/error bars/error mark}%
            {\pgfplotserrorbarsmark}%
            \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/error bars/error mark options}%
            {\pgfplotserrorbarsmarkopts}%
            \path ##1 -- ##2;
        },
        /pgfplots/table/.cd,
        y index=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/box plot whisker bottom index},
        y error expr={
            \thisrowno{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/box plot box bottom index}}
            - \thisrowno{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/box plot whisker bottom index}}
        },
        /pgfplots/box plot
    },
    box plot median/.style={
        /pgfplots/box plot,
        /pgfplots/table/y index=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/box plot median index}
    },
    box plot width/.initial=1em,
    box plot x index/.initial=0,
    box plot median index/.initial=1,
    box plot box top index/.initial=2,
    box plot box bottom index/.initial=3,
    box plot whisker top index/.initial=4,
    box plot whisker bottom index/.initial=5,
    only row/.style={
            x filter/.code={\ifnum\coordindex=#1\else\def\pgfmathresult{nan}\fi}
    }
}

\newcommand{\boxplot}[2][]{
    \addplot [box plot median,#1] table {#2};
    \addplot [forget plot, box plot box,#1] table {#2};
    \addplot [forget plot, box plot top whisker,#1] table {#2};
    \addplot [forget plot, box plot bottom whisker,#1] table {#2};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [xtick={0,1},  xmin=-1,  xmax =2,  xticklabels={test,test2},   box plot width=5mm]
\boxplot [black, forget plot, only row=0]{dataOne.dat}
\boxplot [red, forget plot, only row=1]{dataOne.dat}
\addplot[color = black, mark = *, nodes near coords,every node near coord/.style={anchor=180}]coordinates {( 0, -1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works. It also makes me wonder if there is a better way to do my data, because this requires some care in setting it up (which I guess is ok).

Comment: @enderland: You could apply the filter to a particular column of your data, if that would make it easier.