# Plotting R boxplots with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, best-practices, r, boxplot

I use quite a number of boxplots in my writing, and have chosen `pgfplots` as my plotting solution for a number of reasons (one of which is the benefit of having the data to build the plot in the `tex` file itself).

The state of affairs regarding boxplots in `pgfplots 1.8+` has improved a lot since [I first started using them](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84541/simpler-boxplots-in-pgfplots-is-this-possible), but since I normally use `R` for analysing my data, and since this strikes me as a relatively common setup, I was wondering how people did it, to see if we can come to a common best approach.

tl;dr: **If you use `R` and `pgfplots`, how do you make your boxplots?**

Comment: pgfplots is a must? You can also build the plot in the tex file itself using R without pgfplots with Sweave.

Comment: Definitely not a must, but I prefer to keep a unified visual aesthetic for my plots throughout my document, and I've found I can achieve this more easily by using the same tool for everything. That said, I've never actually got `Sweave` to work, so that might have factored into this. An example would be a welcome addition! :P

Comment: Done. See my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what I've started using recently, since understanding more or less how to use the new boxplot interface of `pgfplots`. Although I know it's not particularly pretty (how could it be? I'm by no means an `R` programmer...), it does get the job done. But it would be interesting to see what others have come up with.

EDIT: Since writing this answer, the function I use has expanded quite a bit, and now accepts more options and allows one to output a completely specified `tikzpicture` environment. Still on the to-do list is to make it accept lists of boxplots to print as sets of groupplot plots. But FWIW, here's the current version. Older versions can be seen in the answers edit history.

This version also makes use of a custom `outid` entry in the R boxplot object, with the id of the outliers. The function will still work if this is not set (and assign numbers as placeholders).

```
pgfbp <- function (bp, figure.opts=c(), axis.opts=c(), plot.opts=c(), standalone=TRUE, tab='\t', caption=c(), label=c(), use.defaults=TRUE, caption.alt=c(), legends=FALSE) {

  indent <- function (tab, n) { return(paste(rep(tab, n), collapse='')) }

  if (!is.list(plot.opts)) {
    plot.opts <- list(plot.opts)
  }

  if (standalone) {
    axis.default <- c(
      'boxplot/draw direction=y',
      paste('xtick={', paste(1:ncol(bp$stats), collapse=', '), '}', sep=''),
      paste('xticklabels={', paste(bp$names, collapse=', '), '}', sep='')
    )
    if (use.defaults) {
      axis.opts <- append(axis.opts, axis.default, 0)
    }

    message('\\begin{figure}', appendLF=FALSE)
    if (length(label)) {
      message(' % fig:', label)
    } else {
      message('')
    }

    t <- indent(tab, 1)
    message(t, '\\centering')
    message(t, '\\begin{tikzpicture}', appendLF=FALSE)

    if (length(figure.opts)) {
      message('[')
      t <- indent(tab, 3)
      for (opt in figure.opts) {
        message(t, opt, ',')
      }
      t <- indent(tab, 2)
      message(t, ']')
    } else {
      message('')
    }

    message(t, '\\begin{axis}', appendLF=FALSE)
    if (length(axis.opts)) {
      message('[')
      t <- indent(tab, 4)
      for (opt in axis.opts) {
        message(t, opt, ',')
      }
      t <- indent(tab, 3)
      message(t, ']')
    } else {
      message('')
    }

  } else {
    t <- indent(tab, 0)
  }

  for (c in 1:ncol(bp$stats)) {
    options <- plot.opts[[((c - 1) %% length(plot.opts)) + 1]]
    # Boxplot name
    message(t, '% ', bp$names[c], '')
    # Boxplot command
    message(t, '\\addplot+[')
    # Options for each boxplot
    tt <- indent(tab, 1)
    # Boxplot prepared quantities
    message(t, tt, 'boxplot prepared={%')
    tt <- indent(tab, 2)
    message(t, tt, 'lower whisker  = ', bp$stats[1,c], ',')
    message(t, tt, 'lower quartile = ', bp$stats[2,c], ',')
    message(t, tt, 'median         = ', bp$stats[3,c], ',')
    message(t, tt, 'upper quartile = ', bp$stats[4,c], ',')
    message(t, tt, 'upper whisker  = ', bp$stats[5,c], ',')
    message(t, tt, 'sample size    = ', bp$n[c], ',')
    tt <- indent(tab, 1)
    message(t, tt, '},')
    for (opt in options) {
      message(t, tt, opt, ',')
    }
    # Outliers
    out <- bp$out[bp$group==c]
    if (length(out) == 0) {
      message(t, '] coordinates {};')
    } else {
      message(t, '] table[y index=0, meta=id, row sep=\\\\] {')
      tt <- indent(tab, 1)
      message(t, tt, 'x id \\\\')
      for (o in 1:length(out)) {
        id <- if (!is.null(bp$outid)) { bp$outid[o] } else { o }
        message(t, tt, out[o], ' ', id, ' \\\\')
      }
      message(t, '};')
    }
    if (legends) {
      message(t, '\\addlegendentry{', bp$names[c], '}')
    }
  }

  if (standalone) {
    t <- indent(tab, 2)
    message(t, '\\end{axis}')
    t <- indent(tab, 1)
    message(t, '\\end{tikzpicture}')
    if (length(caption)) {
      message(t, '\\caption', appendLF=FALSE)
      if (length(caption.alt)) {
        message('[', caption.alt, ']', appendLF=FALSE)
      }
      message('{', caption, '}', appendLF=FALSE)
    }
    if (length(label)) {
      message(t, '\\label{fig:', label, '}', appendLF=FALSE)
    }
    message('\\end{figure}')
  }
}
```

In `R`, you can then save the boxplot object and pass it as an argument to `pgfbp`:

```
boxplot(response ~ group, data=data) -> bp
pgfbp(bp)
```

and copy the output to your `tex` file.

## Labeling outliers

As for the `meta` column, the reason I included it in this function is because sometimes (particularly when showing initial plots to my supervisor) it is useful to label the outliers to be able to identify unusual tendencies in a single participant. This I do together with a pgfplots style:

```
\pgfplotsset{
  label outliers/.style={
    mark size=0,
    nodes near coords,
    every node near coord/.style={
      font=\tiny,
      anchor=center
    },
    point meta=explicit symbolic,
  },
}
```

but I still have to find a good solution for extracting the labels for each outlier from the data (I have a kludge put together from a previous version, but I thought this was a bit too specific for this question). The version above uses numbers as placeholders, but they are easy to remove if they are not used.

Answer (score 5):

Without `pgfplots`  you can insert chunks of R code directly in the text file and obtain the results of this chunks  (text, tables or figures) instead of the R code in the PDF file.

The source file must have the extension `.Rnw` (R noweb) that  R with the Sweave fuction (or `knitr`)  convert in a normal `.tex` that you compile as usual. If you use `rstudio` the editor can make all the steps for you with one click.

[image: MWE]

```
% File example.Rnw
% compile with:
% R CMD Sweave example.Rnw
% pdflatex example.tex  
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
<<echo=F,fig=T>>=
a <- c(1,23,42,13,33,56,23,45,87) 
boxplot(a, col="cyan")
@
\caption{This is R boxplot in a \LaTeX\ file}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Edit**

Using [knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/) instead of Sweave, you can include in the chunk options a  R tikz device  (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/330486/11604) for an example) and use the same fonts that in the rest of the document,  or even include LaTeX formulas in the R graph, so looking as a true LaTeX graph. I rarely worry about this, since I like different fonts in graphics and main text, but may be a good idea using R and pgfplots graphs in the same document, for instance.

Comment: yes, but this isn't a vector graphic

Comment: @skan Not true. R can produce bitmap images (as PNG or TIFF format) , but also PDF and SVG graphics, that are vectorial.  In this case is not a bitmap inside a PDF, but a PDF graph inside a PDF. You can edit the final PDF with Inkscape, for instance, ungroup the graph  and edit each part of the figure as normal vectorial objects.

Comment: Yes but then you need to explicitly tell it to save the plot as a vectorial format, such as svg, with ggsave, svglite, gridsvg or whatever option you prefer. If not, you will end up having a bitmap inside a pdf.

Comment: @skan Nope. If you do not believe me, render my example, where is not set any output device nor any save function, and  check  the result.

Comment: @skan From the [Sweave User Manual](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/doc/Sweave.pdf) (page 2): " Sweave creates (by default)
a **PDF file of the plot** created by the commands in the chunk".