# Plot from data, and linear regression

Tags: math-mode, plot, graphs, gnuplot

I used gnuplot to plot this data

```
0.20    0.41
0.40    0.67
0.75    1.10
2.35    2.20
1.35    1.45
0.25    0.26
1.20    1.22
```

This is the code

```
set xlabel "t"
set ylabel "ln{{T_n-T_e}{T_w -T_e}}"


fit t*x 'data.txt' via t

unset key

plot 'data.txt', t*x
```

and its graph.

It is not possible to set the y axis a the expression [image]

[image]

Comment: No idea in gnuplot, but in R plots with the tikzDevice you can include LaTeX equations in plot labels like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/330486/11604).

Comment: Why not use pgfplots instead of gnuplot?

Comment: Kindly see my Tikz-solution here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/712310/245790 . // Are you sure you intended to post a La/TeX related question here? If so, please add some information in your question to give us some idea, what you try to achieve. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it in `Tikz` as [Andrey L](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/712105/plot-from-data-and-linear-regression#comment1770146_712105) suggested:

- see the [pgfplots manual](https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/) for details (or on ctan)
- your posted data miss one point, so there's a difference
- you should add some names to your data

```
X       Y
0.20    0.41
0.40    0.67
0.75    1.10
2.35    2.20
1.35    1.45
0.25    0.26
1.20    1.22
```

[image: result]

Basic hierarchical structure:

- new `tikzpicture` environment
- inside `tikzpicture`: new `axis` environment
- inside `axis`: add as many plots as you need via `\addplot`
- specify details for `axis`, `addplot` or `table`, see below, i.e. do it in the right place

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    % ~~~ frame, title, labels etc. ~~~~~~~~~~
    \begin{axis}[
        title=Whatever title you want here,
        xlabel={$t$ [s]},
        ylabel=$\ln{\frac{T_H-T_e}{T_w-T_e}}$,
    ]
    % ~~~ first curve or data ~~~~~~~~~~~
    \addplot [
        only marks,
        mark=+,
    ] table {data.txt}; 
    % ~~~ adding a regression ~~~~~~
    \addplot [
        dotted,
        teal,
    ] table [
        y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}},
      ] {data.txt}; 
    \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```