# Boxplot in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, boxplot

I am new to LaTeX. How can I draw a boxplot in LaTeX. My data set is as below

```
index median box_top box_bottom whisker_top whisker_bottom
0 1 1.2 0.4 1.5 0.2
1 2 2.3 1.5 2.7 1
2 0.7 1.4 0.5 1.9 0.1
```

I am using Kile on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

EDIT: Code is added with output.

```
    \documentclass{minimal}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepackage{filecontents}

    \begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat}
     0 1 1.2 0.4 1.5 0.2
     1 2 2.3 1.5 2.7 1
     2 0.7 1.4 0.5 1.9 0.1
     3 1 1.2 0.4 1.5 0.2
     4 2 2.3 1.5 2.7 1
     5 0.7 1.4 0.5 1.9 0.1
    \end{filecontents}

    \pgfplotsset{
     box plot width/.initial=1em,
     box plot/.style={
        /pgfplots/.cd,
        black,
        only marks,
        mark=-,
        mark size=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/box plot width},
        /pgfplots/error bars/.cd,
        y dir=plus,
        y explicit,
     },
     box plot box/.style={
        /pgfplots/error bars/draw error bar/.code 2 args={%
            \draw  ##1 -- ++(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/box plot width},0pt) |- ##2 -- ++(-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/box plot width},0pt) |- ##1 -- cycle;
        },
        /pgfplots/table/.cd,
        y index=2,
        y error expr={\thisrowno{3}-\thisrowno{2}},
        /pgfplots/box plot
     },
     box plot top whisker/.style={
        /pgfplots/error bars/draw error bar/.code 2 args={%
            \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/error bars/error mark}%
            {\pgfplotserrorbarsmark}%
            \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/error bars/error mark options}%
            {\pgfplotserrorbarsmarkopts}%
            \path ##1 -- ##2;
        },
        /pgfplots/table/.cd,
        y index=4,
        y error expr={\thisrowno{2}-\thisrowno{4}},
        /pgfplots/box plot
     },
     box plot bottom whisker/.style={
        /pgfplots/error bars/draw error bar/.code 2 args={%
            \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/error bars/error mark}%
            {\pgfplotserrorbarsmark}%
            \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/error bars/error mark options}%
            {\pgfplotserrorbarsmarkopts}%
            \path ##1 -- ##2;
        },
        /pgfplots/table/.cd,
        y index=5,
        y error expr={\thisrowno{3}-\thisrowno{5}},
        /pgfplots/box plot
     },
     box plot median/.style={
        /pgfplots/box plot
     }
    }

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [enlarge x limits=0.5,xtick=data, box plot width=0.5em]
     \addplot [box plot median] table {testdata.dat};
     \addplot [box plot box] table {testdata.dat};
     \addplot [box plot top whisker] table {testdata.dat};
     \addplot [box plot bottom whisker] table {testdata.dat};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT 2:  here is the actual data I am trying to plot

```
%index median box_top box_bottom whisker_top whisker_bottom
0.52 21.5 191.5 4 150842.5 3
0.53 17 71.5 3 30840.5 2
0.54 5 1 2 2799 1
0.55 9 54 3 2425 2
0.56 4 11.5 2 643.5 1
0.57 3 10 2 124 1
```

Comment: this blog may help you http://blog.ufes.br/fabiomolinares/category/latex/

Comment: I tried this, it is giving me vertical V as drawing

Comment: How about http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84541/simpler-boxplots-in-pgfplots-is-this-possible

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3983/can-i-use-pgfplots-to-make-a-boxplot?rq=1

Comment: pgfplots comes with a "statistics" library which can compute and/or draw box plots (as of version 1.8), see http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots

Comment: All I am getting from codes mentioned in above links in a zigzag line with points as median

Comment: CAn Someone please help me as I an not getting a simple box plot from any example given at any website, all I am getting is zigzag curve.

Answer (score 27):

Boxplots are described in chapter 5.9.1 of the [PGFPLOTS manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf).
[EDIT chapter 5.12.1 as of pgfplots v. 1.13]

Using your data with the examples in the manual I get:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [
    ytick={1,2,3},
    yticklabels={Index 0, Index 1, Index 2},
    ]
    \addplot+[
    boxplot prepared={
      median=1,
      upper quartile=1.2,
      lower quartile=0.4,
      upper whisker=1.5,
      lower whisker=0.2
    },
    ] coordinates {};
    \addplot+[
    boxplot prepared={
      median=2,
      upper quartile=2.3,
      lower quartile=1.5,
      upper whisker=2.7,
      lower whisker=1
    },
    ] coordinates {};
    \addplot+[
    boxplot prepared={
      median=0.7,
      upper quartile=1.4,
      lower quartile=0.5,
      upper whisker=1.9,
      lower whisker=0.1
    },
    ] coordinates {};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Stil a zigzag line.

Comment: You need version 1.8 of pgfplots. It won't work with earlier versions.

Comment: How can I check version of pgfplot on my system?

Comment: Open a terminal window and type `texdoc pgfplots`. This will open a PDF file with the documentation. The version number is listed on the first page of the documentation.

Comment: or else add `\listfiles` before you `\begin{document}` and check the `log` file

Comment: What if I need to display the box plots vertically?

Comment: I can reproduce the example in this answer using pgfplots 1.13, but didn't expect that from reading the comments to this answer.

Comment: @tsigalko18 `\begin{axis}[ boxplot/draw direction=y]`