# Pgfplots and confidential data

Tags: pgfplots

I have a table which contains confidential informations but there is no problem to publish the boxplot resulting of the table.

To produce the boxplot, I am using pfgplot, which reads directly the data from the table.

Is it safe to use the resulting boxplot from pgfplot, in the sense that no data from my table will be included (eg. as metadata) in the resulting pdf file ?

Comment: Can't you just use the 'boxplot prepared' handler so that the data confidential data is never going into LaTeX in the first place?

Comment: I will do as you say, eventhough it is a little bit more complicated : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117435/read-boxplot-prepared-values-from-a-table

Comment: Well, every plot can be reverse engineered and also if it is a vector graphic it is easier to get the coordinates. So better not publish your plot if you have serious concerns. Otherwise rely on the reader's laziness.

Comment: @percusse: I think Laurent is not concerned with people getting the values of the box plot, but with people getting the values that were used to calculate the box plot values (the box plot values are only summary statistics of the confidential data).

Comment: Create a pdf with pgfplot in `standalone` and include it as an image?

Comment: @Jake Oh then I would say yes it is safe since pgfplots only produce paths. I wish it was unsafe though, I could use that hack forever :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are safe to publish the resulting vector graphics.

Please confirm that you generate the graphics as follows:

From what you said, I assume you are using the `statistics` library and its `boxplot` plot handler as in the following example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[y=1cm,ytick=\empty]
    \addplot+[boxplot]
        table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        1\\ 2\\ 1\\ 5\\ 4\\ 10\\
        7\\ 10\\ 9\\ 8\\ 9\\ 9\\
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In this case, pgfplots computes a `boxplot prepared` out of the input data. The values of this `boxplot prepared` are (a) visible and (b) can be reverse engineered. But the original table values are unavailable from the resulting vector graphics (except for any outliers, of course).

---

Unrelated side-remark:

Note that this answer holds only for `boxplot`. If you had a scatter plot or a line plot, the entire coordinate data could be reverse engineered. In fact, the `clickable` library of pgfplots allows not only to reverse engineer any coordinate, but also contains a copy of the input coordinates in the resulting `.pdf`.