# pgfplots boxplot first column as draw position

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, boxplot, tikz-datavisualization

I have data like this in a file.

```
1 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.8 ...
5 0.3 0.5 0.6 0.9 ...
10 0.2 0.3 0.7 0.10 ..
...
```

How do I tell boxplot to use the first column as draw position and compute the box for the rest of the data ?

Following is an example, I want to use 5 and 8 as drawing position.

```
   \documentclass[crop=false]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
    \makeatletter
    \pgfplotsset{
        boxplot prepared from table/.code={
            \def\tikz@plot@handler{\pgfplotsplothandlerboxplotprepared}%
            \pgfplotsset{
                /pgfplots/boxplot prepared from table/.cd,
                #1,
            }
        },
        /pgfplots/boxplot prepared from table/.cd,
            table/.code={\pgfplotstablecopy{#1}\to\boxplot@datatable},
            row/.initial=0,
            make style readable from table/.style={
                #1/.code={
                    \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/boxplot prepared from table/row}}{##1}\of\boxplot@datatable
                    \pgfplotsset{boxplot/#1/.expand once={\pgfplotsretval}}
                }
            },
            make style readable from table=lower whisker,
            make style readable from table=upper whisker,
            make style readable from table=lower quartile,
            make style readable from table=upper quartile,
            make style readable from table=median,
            make style readable from table=lower notch,
            make style readable from table=upper notch
    }
    \makeatother


    \pgfplotstableread{
        index lw lq med  uq uw
        5  5  7 8.5 9.5 10
        8  4  5 6.5 8.5 9.5
    }\datatable


    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[boxplot/draw direction=y]
      \addplot+[
      boxplot prepared from table={
        table=\datatable,
        lower whisker=lw,
        upper whisker=uw,
        lower quartile=lq,
        upper quartile=uq,
        median=med
      }, boxplot prepared
      ]
      coordinates {};
      \addplot+[
      boxplot prepared from table={
        table=\datatable,
        row=1,
        lower whisker=lw,
        upper whisker=uw,
        lower quartile=lq,
        upper quartile=uq,
        median=med
      }, boxplot prepared
      ]
      coordinates {};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you by posting a minimum working example with fully compilable code, illustrating your problem.

Comment: added an example i'm working on

Comment: Related (the basis of the code sample): http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117435/2552

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just can use the option `draw position`, see the manual in section 5.12, pp. 470.

Edited Code:

```
\documentclass[crop=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    boxplot prepared from table/.code={
        \def\tikz@plot@handler{\pgfplotsplothandlerboxplotprepared}%
        \pgfplotsset{
            /pgfplots/boxplot prepared from table/.cd,
            #1,
        }
    },
    /pgfplots/boxplot prepared from table/.cd,
        table/.code={\pgfplotstablecopy{#1}\to\boxplot@datatable},
        row/.initial=0,
        make style readable from table/.style={
            #1/.code={
                \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/boxplot prepared from table/row}}{##1}\of\boxplot@datatable
                \pgfplotsset{boxplot/#1/.expand once={\pgfplotsretval}}
            }
        },
        make style readable from table=lower whisker,
        make style readable from table=upper whisker,
        make style readable from table=lower quartile,
        make style readable from table=upper quartile,
        make style readable from table=median,
        make style readable from table=lower notch,
        make style readable from table=draw position,
        make style readable from table=upper notch
}
\makeatother


\pgfplotstableread{
    index lw lq med  uq uw
    5  5  7 8.5 9.5 10
    8  4  5 6.5 8.5 9.5
}\datatable


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[boxplot/draw direction=y]
  \addplot+[
  boxplot prepared from table={
    table=\datatable,
    lower whisker=lw,
    upper whisker=uw,
    lower quartile=lq,
    upper quartile=uq,
    median=med
  }, boxplot prepared={,},
  ]
  coordinates {};

  \addplot+[
  boxplot prepared from table={
    table=\datatable,
    row=1,
    lower whisker=lw,
    upper whisker=uw,
    lower quartile=lq,
    upper quartile=uq,
    draw position = index,
    median=med,
  }, boxplot prepared={},
  ]
  coordinates {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```