# Two aligned axes above each other with different x-axis values

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to generate two different axes above each other with the bottom one being a more zoomed in version of the x-axis of the top one. The data is fetched from a csv file.

[The CSV reading and generating is based on this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399163/create-boxplots-from-file)

[An example of what I'm trying to accomplish](https://tech.channable.com/images/aho-perf-before.svg) from [this article](https://tech.channable.com/posts/2019-03-13-how-we-made-haskell-search-strings-as-fast-as-rust.html) (I'm not the author).

I've got the following code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
  boxplot prepared from table/.code={
    \def\tikz@plot@handler{\pgfplotsplothandlerboxplotprepared}%
    \pgfplotsset{
      /pgfplots/boxplot prepared from table/.cd,
      #1,
    }
  },
  /pgfplots/boxplot prepared from table/.cd,
  table/.code={\pgfplotstablecopy{#1}\to\boxplot@datatable},
  row/.initial=0,
  make style readable from table/.style={
    #1/.code={
      \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/boxplot prepared from table/row}}{##1}\of\boxplot@datatable
      \pgfplotsset{boxplot/#1/.expand once={\pgfplotsretval}}
    }
  },
  make style readable from table=lower whisker,
  make style readable from table=upper whisker,
  make style readable from table=lower quartile,
  make style readable from table=upper quartile,
  make style readable from table=median,
  make style readable from table=lower notch,
  make style readable from table=upper notch,
  make style readable from table=average
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{./results/request_durations.csv}\datatable
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{./results/request_durations_large.csv}\datatablelarge

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      boxplot,
      xmin=0,
      width=\textwidth,
      scale only axis,
      ytick=\empty,
      /pgfplots/boxplot/box extend=0.3,
      cycle list={},
      name=main plot,
      ]
      \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatablelarge}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\TotalRows{\pgfplotsretval-1}
      \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,\TotalRows}
      {
        \addplot+[
        boxplot prepared from table={
          table=\datatablelarge,
          row=#1,
          lower whisker=min_duration_ms,
          upper whisker=max_duration_ms,
          lower quartile=lower_quartile,
          upper quartile=upper_quartile,
          median=median,
          average=avg_duration_ms,
        },
        boxplot prepared,
        black
        ]
        coordinates {};
        % node [below,inner sep=0.4cm,anchor=south west] at (200,#1+1)
        % {\pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{http}\of\datatablelarge \scriptsize\pgfplotsretval};
      }
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[
      boxplot,
      scale only axis,
      at={(main plot.below south west)},
      xmax=30000,
      width=\textwidth,
      ytick=\empty,
      /pgfplots/boxplot/box extend=0.3,
      cycle list={},
      yshift=0.1cm,
      ]
      \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatable}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\TotalRows{\pgfplotsretval-1}
      \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,\TotalRows}
      {
        \addplot+[
        boxplot prepared from table={
          table=\datatable,
          row=#1,
          lower whisker=min_duration_ms,
          upper whisker=max_duration_ms,
          lower quartile=lower_quartile,
          upper quartile=upper_quartile,
          median=median,
          average=avg_duration_ms,
        },
        boxplot prepared,
        black
        ]
        coordinates {};
        % node [below,inner sep=0.4cm,anchor=south west] at (200,#1+1)
        % {\pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{http}\of\datatable \scriptsize\pgfplotsretval};
      }
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Response times in milliseconds}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

.. but this results in the following oddly overlapping figure:

[image: faulty overlapping axes]

Heres an example of the csv files (they're the same format; slightly bigger x-axis data in the other):

```
http,frequency,min_duration_ms,lower_quartile,median,upper_quartile,max_duration_ms,avg_duration_ms,stddev_duration_ms,iqr
GET /endpoint,525,128,628,892,1398,2963,962,410,2835
```

The lines between them aside, how do I even get them to stack on top of each other properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to add a proper `anchor` ...

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      name=main plot,
    ]
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[
      at={(main plot.below south west)},
      anchor=north west,    % <-- added
      yshift=-1ex,          % <-- adjusted
      ]
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]