# boxplot prepared from table, accessed using row names instead of numbers

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, expansion, boxplot

I have csv files<sup>1</sup> that I want to plot as boxplots. I found the solution to that part of the problem [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117439/74413) (courtesy of Jake), and that constitutes a large part of my MWE.

The difference here is that I want to be able produce each boxplot from a row *name* rather than *number*. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    boxplot prepared from table/.code={
        \def\tikz@plot@handler{\pgfplotsplothandlerboxplotprepared}%
        \pgfplotsset{
            /pgfplots/boxplot prepared from table/.cd,
            #1,
        }
    },
    /pgfplots/boxplot prepared from table/.cd,
        table/.code={\pgfplotstablecopy{#1}\to\boxplot@datatable},
        row/.initial=0,
        make style readable from table/.style={
            #1/.code={
                \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/boxplot prepared from table/row}}{##1}\of\boxplot@datatable
                \pgfplotsset{boxplot/#1/.expand once={\pgfplotsretval}}
            }
        },
        make style readable from table=lower whisker,
        make style readable from table=upper whisker,
        make style readable from table=lower quartile,
        make style readable from table=upper quartile,
        make style readable from table=median,
        make style readable from table=lower notch,
        make style readable from table=upper notch,
                make style readable from table=average
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\computerowindex}[2]{
\def\xindex{-1}
\pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement{x}\of#1\as\cell{%
\edef\cellname{#2}
    \ifx\cell\cellname\let\xindex\pgfplotstablerow\fi   
}
}
\newcommand{\boxplotprepared}[2]{
\computerowindex{#1}{#2}
\expandafter\boxplotpreparedNum\expandafter#1\xindex
}

\newcommand{\boxplotpreparedNum}[2]{

\addplot[boxplot prepared from table={
    table=#1,
    row=#2,
    average=mean,
    lower whisker = min,
    upper whisker = max,
    lower quartile = fq,
    upper quartile = tq,
    median=median},
    boxplot prepared]
coordinates {};
%
}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
x   min qu2 fq  median  tq  max mean
a1  19.9    21.384  25.175  28.05   31.425  44.6    28.366
a2  22.4    24  26.975  29.4    31.65   45.6    29.509
a3  29.1    29.398  32.1    34.9    38.175  48.9    35.582
b1  33.5    34.494  41.3    46.15   54.725  108.1   49.749
b2  39.2    41.662  52.625  64.1    83.3    126.3   69.364
b3  42.7    45.092  66.2    80.05   102.8   213.2   88.251
c1  54.4    56.76   75.5    107.9   135.45  195.7   109.501
c2  54.7    59  96.8    123.45  152.725 331.2   132.139
c3  64.7    65.99   102.95  139 200.025 348.2   153.915
d1  74.4    86.818  136.9   176.25  221.925 503.4   189.913
d2  80.6    100.508 144.175 191.7   247.5   454.1   205.501
d3  73.3    110.804 174.15  227.5   294.7   632.3   247.584
e1  98.2    111.55  163.1   222.15  300.05  512.4   240.966
e2  110.9   112.768 181.125 236.4   325.975 719.3   266.793
}{\loadedtable}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
             boxplot/draw direction=y,
             boxplot/average={auto},
             boxplot/every average/.style={/tikz/mark=*,mark size=1},
             ymin=0,ymax=800]
\boxplotprepared{\loadedtable}{a1}
\boxplotprepared{\loadedtable}{a2}
\boxplotprepared{\loadedtable}{a3}
\boxplotprepared{\loadedtable}{b1}
\boxplotprepared{\loadedtable}{b2}
\boxplotprepared{\loadedtable}{b3}
\boxplotprepared{\loadedtable}{c1}
\boxplotprepared{\loadedtable}{c2}
\boxplotprepared{\loadedtable}{c3}
\boxplotprepared{\loadedtable}{d1}
\boxplotprepared{\loadedtable}{d2}
\boxplotprepared{\loadedtable}{d3}
\boxplotprepared{\loadedtable}{e1}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This works fine for row numbers less than 10, but as soon as it hits double digits, it truncates the number and uses row 1 instead of 10, 11, 12, etc. The problem is here

```
\newcommand{\boxplotprepared}[2]{
\computerowindex{#1}{#2}
\expandafter\boxplotpreparedNum\expandafter#1\xindex
}
```

If I understand correctly, `\expandafter` is causing `\xinput` to be evaluated the number `12` (for example) first, so `\boxplotpreparedNum` takes `1` as its second argument and the second digit gets just gets lost because it's floating around inside an `axis` environment. Those `\expandafter` commands seem to be necessary though. I get errors if I take either of them away, and nonsense output if I take both. I thought using `\let` or `\edef` to define `\xinput` would make them unnecessary, and I can't work out why they don't.

If there's a way to include braces around the argument even with the `\expandafter` command there, that would be the simplest solution, but no combination I've tried works, so I'm not even sure if it's possible.

How can I get this to work?

<sub>1. Note that I've defined the table directly in the code of my MWE; as far as I'm aware, it is immaterial to the current problem.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I was on the right track thinking about the braces. What I didn't realise is that `{` is a token, so adding braces requires one additional `\expandafter`:

```
\newcommand{\boxplotprepared}[2]{
\computerowindex{#1}{#2}
\expandafter\boxplotpreparedNum\expandafter#1\expandafter{\xindex}
}
```

[image]

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    boxplot prepared from table/.code={
        \def\tikz@plot@handler{\pgfplotsplothandlerboxplotprepared}%
        \pgfplotsset{
            /pgfplots/boxplot prepared from table/.cd,
            #1,
        }
    },
    /pgfplots/boxplot prepared from table/.cd,
        table/.code={\pgfplotstablecopy{#1}\to\boxplot@datatable},
        row/.initial=0,
        make style readable from table/.style={
            #1/.code={
                \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/boxplot prepared from table/row}}{##1}\of\boxplot@datatable
                \pgfplotsset{boxplot/#1/.expand once={\pgfplotsretval}}
            }
        },
        make style readable from table=lower whisker,
        make style readable from table=upper whisker,
        make style readable from table=lower quartile,
        make style readable from table=upper quartile,
        make style readable from table=median,
        make style readable from table=lower notch,
        make style readable from table=upper notch,
                make style readable from table=average
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\computerowindex}[2]{
\def\xindex{-1}
\pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement{x}\of#1\as\cell{%
\edef\cellname{#2}
    \ifx\cell\cellname\let\xindex\pgfplotstablerow\fi   
}
}
\newcommand{\boxplotprepared}[2]{
\computerowindex{#1}{#2}
\expandafter\boxplotpreparedNum\expandafter#1\expandafter{\xindex}
}

\newcommand{\boxplotpreparedNum}[2]{

\addplot[boxplot prepared from table={
    table=#1,
    row=#2,
    average=mean,
    lower whisker = min,
    upper whisker = max,
    lower quartile = fq,
    upper quartile = tq,
    median=median},
    boxplot prepared]
coordinates {};
%
}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
x   min qu2 fq  median  tq  max mean
a1  19.9    21.384  25.175  28.05   31.425  44.6    28.366
a2  22.4    24  26.975  29.4    31.65   45.6    29.509
a3  29.1    29.398  32.1    34.9    38.175  48.9    35.582
b1  33.5    34.494  41.3    46.15   54.725  108.1   49.749
b2  39.2    41.662  52.625  64.1    83.3    126.3   69.364
b3  42.7    45.092  66.2    80.05   102.8   213.2   88.251
c1  54.4    56.76   75.5    107.9   135.45  195.7   109.501
c2  54.7    59  96.8    123.45  152.725 331.2   132.139
c3  64.7    65.99   102.95  139 200.025 348.2   153.915
d1  74.4    86.818  136.9   176.25  221.925 503.4   189.913
d2  80.6    100.508 144.175 191.7   247.5   454.1   205.501
d3  73.3    110.804 174.15  227.5   294.7   632.3   247.584
e1  98.2    111.55  163.1   222.15  300.05  512.4   240.966
e2  110.9   112.768 181.125 236.4   325.975 719.3   266.793
}{\loadedtable}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
             boxplot/draw direction=y,
             boxplot/average={auto},
             boxplot/every average/.style={/tikz/mark=*,mark size=1},
             ymin=0,ymax=800]
\boxplotprepared{\loadedtable}{a1}
\boxplotprepared{\loadedtable}{a2}
\boxplotprepared{\loadedtable}{a3}
\boxplotprepared{\loadedtable}{b1}
\boxplotprepared{\loadedtable}{b2}
\boxplotprepared{\loadedtable}{b3}
\boxplotprepared{\loadedtable}{c1}
\boxplotprepared{\loadedtable}{c2}
\boxplotprepared{\loadedtable}{c3}
\boxplotprepared{\loadedtable}{d1}
\boxplotprepared{\loadedtable}{d2}
\boxplotprepared{\loadedtable}{d3}
\boxplotprepared{\loadedtable}{e1}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

<sub>If anyone knows a simpler (i.e., more readable) solution, or can post a better (clearer or more accurate) explanation of why my solution works, post it and I'll accept your answer.</sub>