# Problems with whiskers and outliers in boxplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxplot

I'm trying to reproduce a boxplot from MATLAB using LaTeX.
Unfortunately boxplot seems unable to draw outliers and also whiskers have some problems, see figure.
[image]

The first two boxes seem to have problems with their whiskers: they simply shouldn't be present.
Moreover, in the entire plot, outliers are missing, while in the MATLAB version they are present. Here's the MATLAB version:

[image]

This is the LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.statistics}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogyaxis}[
boxplot/draw direction=y,
xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6},
xticklabels={3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
xlabel=number,
ylabel={time[s]},
boxplot/variable width,
boxplot/whisker range={1.57},
]
\addplot[boxplot,box extend=2]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
0.090000 \\ 0.440000 \\ 0.120000 \\ 0.060000 \\ 0.320000 \\ 0.230000 \\ 0.440000 \\ 0.020000 \\ 0.150000 \\ 0.180000 \\ 0.000000 \\ 0.290000 \\ 0.000000 \\ 0.110000 \\ 0.260000 \\ 0.110000 \\ 0.000000 \\ 0.450000 \\ 0.040000 \\ 0.140000 \\ 0.030000 \\ 0.120000 \\ 0.140000 \\ 0.310000 \\ 0.060000 \\ 0.060000 \\ 0.110000 \\ 0.120000 \\ 0.120000 \\ 0.120000 \\ 0.130000 \\ 0.010000 \\ 0.400000 \\ 0.010000 \\ 0.030000 \\ 0.170000 \\ 0.000000 \\ 0.100000 \\ 0.150000 \\ 0.160000 \\ 0.060000 \\ 0.100000 \\ 0.010000 \\ 0.600000 \\ 0.260000 \\ 0.110000 \\ 0.150000 \\ 0.220000 \\ 0.140000 \\ 0.010000 \\ 
};
\addplot[boxplot,box extend=2]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
0.070000 \\ 0.490000 \\ 0.340000 \\ 0.200000 \\ 0.020000 \\ 1.080000 \\ 6.830000 \\ 0.310000 \\ 0.540000 \\ 0.020000 \\ 0.290000 \\ 0.180000 \\ 0.600000 \\ 0.090000 \\ 0.610000 \\ 1.370000 \\ 0.260000 \\ 0.030000 \\ 2.300000 \\ 0.090000 \\ 3.150000 \\ 0.130000 \\ 0.290000 \\ 0.270000 \\ 1.300000 \\ 0.730000 \\ 0.630000 \\ 0.240000 \\ 10.030000 \\ 0.000000 \\ 0.260000 \\ 0.180000 \\ 3.290000 \\ 2.430000 \\ 1.940000 \\ 0.220000 \\ 0.230000 \\ 0.600000 \\ 1.690000 \\ 0.350000 \\ 3.960000 \\ 0.560000 \\ 9.900000 \\ 0.100000 \\ 0.430000 \\ 0.220000 \\ 0.260000 \\ 0.310000 \\ 0.290000 \\ 0.790000 \\ 
};
\addplot[boxplot,box extend=2]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
12.700000 \\ 1.340000 \\ 0.680000 \\ 0.510000 \\ 1.770000 \\ 0.040000 \\ 3.790000 \\ 287.050000 \\ 1.350000 \\ 5.410000 \\ 15.560000 \\ 3.130000 \\ 0.910000 \\ 7.480000 \\ 2.400000 \\ 1.040000 \\ 3.530000 \\ 0.580000 \\ 31.710000 \\ 7.890000 \\ 4.900000 \\ 2.610000 \\ 0.890000 \\ 0.030000 \\ 3.780000 \\ 8.110000 \\ 4.820000 \\ 1.020000 \\ 5.570000 \\ 8.850000 \\ 0.150000 \\ 17.590000 \\ 0.210000 \\ 8.100000 \\ 2.150000 \\ 3.430000 \\ 6.440000 \\ 1.650000 \\ 6.830000 \\ 23.540000 \\ 0.520000 \\ 1.470000 \\ 0.750000 \\ 3.540000 \\ 3.590000 \\ 5.560000 \\ 0.330000 \\ 8.580000 \\ 1.900000 \\ 0.780000 \\ 
};
\addplot[boxplot,box extend=2]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
55.720000 \\ 14.910000 \\ 14.950000 \\ 6.010000 \\ 6.530000 \\ 88.300000 \\ 281.500000 \\ 40.150000 \\ 13.410000 \\ 0.910000 \\ 1.650000 \\ 44.320000 \\ 13.410000 \\ 7.330000 \\ 3.510000 \\ 3.440000 \\ 70.400000 \\ 0.750000 \\ 58.200000 \\ 54.880000 \\ 26.450000 \\ 33.760000 \\ 0.700000 \\ 0.050000 \\ 0.290000 \\ 57.120000 \\ 14.300000 \\ 31.110000 \\ 18.560000 \\ 0.480000 \\ 21.330000 \\ 1.150000 \\ 2.220000 \\ 3.880000 \\ 1.780000 \\ 151.250000 \\ 7.770000 \\ 137.920000 \\ 0.500000 \\ 3.010000 \\ 1.990000 \\ 23.180000 \\ 119.590000 \\ 17.500000 \\ 15.870000 \\ 13.630000 \\ 21.850000 \\ 23.530000 \\ 68.720000 \\ 2.900000 \\ 
};
\addplot[boxplot,box extend=2]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
1.190000 \\ 1.940000 \\ 13.400000 \\ 7.400000 \\ 267.300000 \\ 5.940000 \\ 11.050000 \\ 6.510000 \\ 2.940000 \\ 5.450000 \\ 5.240000 \\ 231.000000 \\ 4.480000 \\ 0.680000 \\ 311.290000 \\ 77.470000 \\ 621.200000 \\ 139.080000 \\ 1933.590000 \\ 2.520000 \\ 100.960000 \\ 11.020000 \\ 153.430000 \\ 26.670000 \\ 83.840000 \\ 4.310000 \\ 106.340000 \\ 15.900000 \\ 1118.590000 \\ 9.490000 \\ 131.480000 \\ 48.920000 \\ 5.850000 \\ 3.740000 \\ 1.050000 \\ 32.030000 \\ 5.690000 \\ 45.100000 \\ 12.430000 \\ 238.560000 \\ 28.750000 \\ 1.010000 \\ 119.290000 \\ 12.090000 \\ 31.180000 \\ 16.600000 \\ 29.670000 \\ 138.550000 \\ 17.420000 \\ 0.830000 \\ 
};
\addplot[boxplot,box extend=2]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
2077.450000 \\ 762.100000 \\ 469.000000 \\ 143.600000 \\ 685.000000 \\ 3600.000000 \\ 20.200000 \\ 249.600000 \\ 269.000000 \\ 0.300000 \\ 0.200000 \\ 779.400000 \\ 1.800000 \\ 146.800000 \\ 1.300000 \\ 32.500000 \\ 137.000000 \\ 2016.400000 \\ 2.300000 \\ 33.900000 \\ 801.600000 \\ 2.200000 \\ 646.900000 \\ 3600.000000 \\ 1184.000000 \\ 627.000000 \\ 500.500000 \\ 238.300000 \\ 477.400000 \\ 3600.000000 \\ 17.800000 \\ 1726.800000 \\ 2.000000 \\ 316.700000 \\ 174.500000 \\ 2802.700000 \\ 335.300000 \\ 201.200000 \\ 1.100000 \\ 247.100000 \\ 2705.100000 \\ 156.900000 \\ 5.100000 \\ 2342.500000 \\ 3600.000000 \\ 3600.000000 \\ 72.700000 \\ 47.400000 \\ 301.200000 \\ 1.600000 \\ 
};
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I also tried to follow [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115210/boxplot-in-latex) answer's code but something's wrong using my data. I cannot understand what I'm doing wrong.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat}
3 0.090000 0.440000 0.120000 0.060000 0.320000 0.230000 0.440000 0.020000 0.150000 0.180000 0.000000 0.290000 0.000000 0.110000 0.260000 0.110000 0.000000 0.450000 0.040000 0.140000 0.030000 0.120000 0.140000 0.310000 0.060000 0.060000 0.110000 0.120000 0.120000 0.120000 0.130000 0.010000 0.400000 0.010000 0.030000 0.170000 0.000000 0.100000 0.150000 0.160000 0.060000 0.100000 0.010000 0.600000 0.260000 0.110000 0.150000 0.220000 0.140000 0.010000 
4 0.070000 0.490000 0.340000 0.200000 0.020000 1.080000 6.830000 0.310000 0.540000 0.020000 0.290000 0.180000 0.600000 0.090000 0.610000 1.370000 0.260000 0.030000 2.300000 0.090000 3.150000 0.130000 0.290000 0.270000 1.300000 0.730000 0.630000 0.240000 10.030000 0.000000 0.260000 0.180000 3.290000 2.430000 1.940000 0.220000 0.230000 0.600000 1.690000 0.350000 3.960000 0.560000 9.900000 0.100000 0.430000 0.220000 0.260000 0.310000 0.290000 0.790000 
5 12.700000 1.340000 0.680000 0.510000 1.770000 0.040000 3.790000 287.050000 1.350000 5.410000 15.560000 3.130000 0.910000 7.480000 2.400000 1.040000 3.530000 0.580000 31.710000 7.890000 4.900000 2.610000 0.890000 0.030000 3.780000 8.110000 4.820000 1.020000 5.570000 8.850000 0.150000 17.590000 0.210000 8.100000 2.150000 3.430000 6.440000 1.650000 6.830000 23.540000 0.520000 1.470000 0.750000 3.540000 3.590000 5.560000 0.330000 8.580000 1.900000 0.780000 
6 55.720000 14.910000 14.950000 6.010000 6.530000 88.300000 281.500000 40.150000 13.410000 0.910000 1.650000 44.320000 13.410000 7.330000 3.510000 3.440000 70.400000 0.750000 58.200000 54.880000 26.450000 33.760000 0.700000 0.050000 0.290000 57.120000 14.300000 31.110000 18.560000 0.480000 21.330000 1.150000 2.220000 3.880000 1.780000 151.250000 7.770000 137.920000 0.500000 3.010000 1.990000 23.180000 119.590000 17.500000 15.870000 13.630000 21.850000 23.530000 68.720000 2.900000 
7 1.190000 1.940000 13.400000 7.400000 267.300000 5.940000 11.050000 6.510000 2.940000 5.450000 5.240000 231.000000 4.480000 0.680000 311.290000 77.470000 621.200000 139.080000 1933.590000 2.520000 100.960000 11.020000 153.430000 26.670000 83.840000 4.310000 106.340000 15.900000 1118.590000 9.490000 131.480000 48.920000 5.850000 3.740000 1.050000 32.030000 5.690000 45.100000 12.430000 238.560000 28.750000 1.010000 119.290000 12.090000 31.180000 16.600000 29.670000 138.550000 17.420000 0.830000 
8 2077.450000 762.100000 469.000000 143.600000 685.000000 3600.000000 20.200000 249.600000 269.000000 0.300000 0.200000 779.400000 1.800000 146.800000 1.300000 32.500000 137.000000 2016.400000 2.300000 33.900000 801.600000 2.200000 646.900000 3600.000000 1184.000000 627.000000 500.500000 238.300000 477.400000 3600.000000 17.800000 1726.800000 2.000000 316.700000 174.500000 2802.700000 335.300000 201.200000 1.100000 247.100000 2705.100000 156.900000 5.100000 2342.500000 3600.000000 3600.000000 72.700000 47.400000 301.200000 1.600000 
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotsset{
    box plot/.style={
        /pgfplots/.cd,
        black,
        only marks,
        mark=-,
        mark size=1em,
        /pgfplots/error bars/.cd,
        y dir=plus,
        y explicit,
    },
    box plot box/.style={
        /pgfplots/error bars/draw error bar/.code 2 args={%
            \draw  ##1 -- ++(1em,0pt) |- ##2 -- ++(-1em,0pt) |- ##1 -- cycle;
        },
        /pgfplots/table/.cd,
        y index=2,
        y error expr={\thisrowno{3}-\thisrowno{2}},
        /pgfplots/box plot
    },
    box plot top whisker/.style={
        /pgfplots/error bars/draw error bar/.code 2 args={%
            \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/error bars/error mark}%
            {\pgfplotserrorbarsmark}%
            \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/error bars/error mark options}%
            {\pgfplotserrorbarsmarkopts}%
            \path ##1 -- ##2;
        },
        /pgfplots/table/.cd,
        y index=4,
        y error expr={\thisrowno{2}-\thisrowno{4}},
        /pgfplots/box plot
    },
    box plot bottom whisker/.style={
        /pgfplots/error bars/draw error bar/.code 2 args={%
            \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/error bars/error mark}%
            {\pgfplotserrorbarsmark}%
            \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/error bars/error mark options}%
            {\pgfplotserrorbarsmarkopts}%
            \path ##1 -- ##2;
        },
        /pgfplots/table/.cd,
        y index=5,
        y error expr={\thisrowno{3}-\thisrowno{5}},
        /pgfplots/box plot
    },
    box plot median/.style={
        /pgfplots/box plot
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [ 
        ymode=log,
        enlarge x limits=0.5,
        xtick=data]
    \addplot [box plot median] table {testdata.dat};
    \addplot [box plot box] table {testdata.dat};
    \addplot [box plot top whisker] table {testdata.dat};
    \addplot [box plot bottom whisker] table {testdata.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: <useless comment> I like your profile picture. </useless comment>

Comment: Real comment: This is not actually a solution but can lead to one. Generate your desired plot in matlab, then export it using [matlab2tikz](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz). It generates a `.tex` file that has axis setting, options and the data. Once you export it, if the results are satisfactory, then try to compare it with your own code to see where are the problems and/or missing options.

Comment: @Pouya Actually I already done that. The problem is that matlab2tikz generates a totally different code, because he doesn't know the real data, he only knows the boxplot properties (median, quartiles, etc). Here the problem seems to be a wrong data processing due to some tikz bug. Here's the matlab2tikz output: http://pastebin.com/H5EPxft0

Answer (score 3):

I discovered the **bug of tikz**: if you note, the wrong whiskers appear to have exactly the same value. Well if you try to calculate them manually they result both 0. What does it happen if one tries to plot a zero value on a log scale without any check? It happens this bug ;-) If you replace 0.000 values with 0.001 values, for example, the whiskers appear correctly. Now I don't know where to signal this bug anyway. Actually the bug IMHO is also on the MATLAB side, as a whisker (maybe endless) should appear in the plot.

A solution to this problem is to remove the 0 values and manage boxs' width in a different way.

A second solution to this problem is to write a simple program which takes data and produces a custom boxplot. The program calculates quartiles, median, whiskers and outliers. When the program finds a zero whiskers it replaces it with a near-to-zero. For this case I used 0.0001.
In this way I was able to produce this plot:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A solution with PSTricks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-2)(9,5)
\psset{fillstyle=solid}
\psaxes[ylogBase=10,Oy=-2,logLines=y,ticksize=0 4pt, subticks=5](1,-2)(9,4)
\rput(3,0){\psBoxplot[fillcolor=red!30,barwidth=0.9cm,postAction=Log]{ 
  0.09 0.44 0.12 0.06 0.32 0.23 0.44 0.02 0.15 0.18 0 0.29 0 0.11 0.26 0.11 0 0.45 0.04 0.14 0.03 0.12 0.14 0.31 0.06 0.06 0.11 0.12 0.12 0.12 0.13 0.01 0.40 0.01 0.03 0.17 0 0.10 0.15 0.16 0.06 0.10 0.01 0.60 0.26 0.11 0.15 0.22 0.14 0.01 }}
 \rput(4,0){\psBoxplot[fillcolor=red!30,barwidth=0.9cm,postAction=Log]{ 
0.07 0.49 0.34 0.20 0.02 1.08 6.83 0.31 0.54 0.02 0.29 0.18 0.60 0.09 0.61 1.37 0.26 0.03 2.30 0.09 3.15 0.13 0.29 0.27 1.30 0.73 0.63 0.24 10.03 0 0.26 0.18 3.29 2.43 1.94 0.22 0.23 0.60 1.69 0.35 3.96 0.56 9.90 0.10 0.43 0.22 0.26 0.31 0.29 0.79 }}
 \rput(5,0){\psBoxplot[fillcolor=red!30,barwidth=0.9cm,postAction=log]{ 
12.70 1.34 0.68 0.51 1.77 0.04 3.79 287.05 1.35 5.41 15.56 3.13 0.91 7.48 2.40 1.04 3.53 0.58 31.71 7.89 4.90 2.61 0.89 0.03 3.78 8.11 4.82 1.02 5.57 8.85 0.15 17.59 0.21 8.10 2.15 3.43 6.44 1.65 6.83 23.54 0.52 1.47 0.75 3.54 3.59 5.56 0.33 8.58 1.90 0.78  }}
 \rput(6,0){\psBoxplot[fillcolor=red!30,barwidth=0.9cm,postAction=log]{ 
55.72 14.91 14.95 6.01 6.53 88.30 281.50 40.15 13.41 0.91 1.65 44.32 13.41 7.33 3.51 3.44 70.40 0.75 58.20 54.88 26.45 33.76 0.70 0.05 0.29 57.12 14.30 31.11 18.56 0.48 21.33 1.15 2.22 3.88 1.78 151.25 7.77 137.92 0.50 3.01 1.99 23.18 119.59 17.50 15.87 13.63 21.85 23.53 68.72 2.90  }}
 \rput(7,0){\psBoxplot[fillcolor=red!30,barwidth=0.9cm,postAction=log]{ 
1.19 1.94 13.40 7.40 267.30 5.94 11.05 6.51 2.94 5.45 5.24 231 4.48 0.68 311.29 77.47 621.20 139.08 1933.59 2.52 100.96 11.02 153.43 26.67 83.84 4.31 106.34 15.90 1118.59 9.49 131.48 48.92 5.85 3.74 1.05 32.03 5.69 45.10 12.43 238.56 28.75 1.01 119.29 12.09 31.18 16.60 29.67 138.55 17.42 0.83  }}
 \rput(8,0){\psBoxplot[fillcolor=red!30,barwidth=0.9cm,postAction=log]{ 
2077.45 762.10 469 143.60 685 3600 20.20 249.60 269 0.30 0.20 779.40 1.80 146.80 1.30 32.50 137 2016.40 2.30 33.90 801.60 2.20 646.90 3600 1184 627 500.50 238.30 477.40 3600 17.80 1726.80 2 316.70 174.50 2802.70 335.30 201.20 1.10 247.10 2705.10 156.90 5.10 2342.50 3600 3600 72.70 47.40 301.20 1.60  }}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

needs pst-plot.tex from http://texnik.dante.de/tex/generic/pst-plot/ and `pstricks.pro` 
http://texnik.dante.de/dvips/pstricks/

[image]

Comment: I cannot give an answer because I implemented only the code for other users without understanding the sense of a boxplot.

Comment: I suppose it is a problem with building the log, because some values in the first two plots are 0. And I am wondering how matlab handles `log(0)`

Comment: @Herbert Would it be a good idea to use, say, `\newpsobject{boxplot}{psBoxplot}{fillcolor = red!30, ylogBase = \Log, barwidth = 0.9cm}` since you have the same options for all the boxplots?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: yes, that makes sense

Comment: @Herbert Yes, as I said in my answer the problem is due to zero values. The problem in MATLAB is automagically resolved with the removal of whisker.

Comment: @HAL9000: Ok, I got it, see edited answer.

Comment: @Herbert I can't find `pst-plot.pro` in any of the two directories. `:(`

Comment: sorry, it should be `pstricks.pro` http://texnik.dante.de/dvips/pstricks/