# Dot and whisker plot in PGFplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, boxplot, statistics

Sometimes it is useful to present the coefficients of a regression with accompanying confidence intervals as a dot-and-whisker plot. See [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dotwhisker/vignettes/dotwhisker-vignette.html) for a motivation of this approach and some examples of what I am trying to achieve based on an R package `dotwhisker` designed to produce these plots. Here is an example from the linked R vignette:
[image]
I would like to replicate similar dot-and-whisker plots in `PGFPLOTS`.

`PGFPLOTS` supports box-and-whisker plots natively -- [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115438/46516) is an example. A full description of the box-and-whisker feature of PGF is in section 5.12.1 of [manual version 1.16](http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf).

Here is my best attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ytick={1,2,3},
    yticklabels={Group A, Group B, Group C},
    ]

\addplot+ [
boxplot prepared={
lower whisker=0.35, 
% lower quartile=,
median=0.6,
% upper quartile=, 
upper whisker=0.85,
},
]
coordinates {};

\addplot+ [
boxplot prepared={
lower whisker=0.55, 
% lower quartile=,
median=0.70,
% upper quartile=, 
upper whisker=0.85,
},
] 
coordinates {};

\addplot+ [
boxplot prepared={
lower whisker=0.85, 
% lower quartile=,
median=0.9,
% upper quartile=, 
upper whisker=0.95,
},
] 
coordinates {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: boxwhisker.PNG]

There are several problems with my attempt:

1. I am adapting the box and whisker feature to represent something
   that is not a box whisker. This is perhaps the wrong way to approach
   things. My *kludge* treats the median as the coefficient estimate,
   and treats the upper and lower whiskers as the upper and lower confidence intervals.
   I comment out the quartiles as I do not have an equivalent for
   these, and I do not want the box.
2. Unlike the `R` package `dotwhister`, the graphics are not clear -- having vertical lines puts too much emphasis on the confidence
   bounds relative to the coefficient point estimate.
3. It is not scalable. I would like to analyse 50 groups. Everytime I update my data I do not want to manually update the box plot
       entries in `PGFPLOTS`. I would prefer to be able to read from a
       `.csv` containing 50 rows for each group and four columns: group
       name, coefficient estimate, upper confidence interval, lower
       confidence interval.

Here is some randomly generated data (`upper` and `lower` are symmetric around `point_est`):

```
\begin{filecontents*}{dotwhisker.csv}
    group,point_est,upper,lower
    SCBQD6600C,0.318940138,0.782642805,-0.144762529
    GHECK1046A,0.541614386,1.425115639,-0.341886867
    ICOOO3242S,0.662666177,1.143455809,0.181876544
    PHOVQ7028A,0.148145345,0.239989182,0.056301508
    HSJEK0588Y,0.564368703,0.997673282,0.131064125
    CYVFG8255L,0.575908384,1.288811424,-0.136994656
    ZDYRJ3242S,0.413789006,0.639376662,0.18820135
    PXQSX1684J,0.418005222,0.974470232,-0.138459788
    VTCRK0417U,0.4153322,1.020437688,-0.189773288
    WSYWC4669M,0.366494326,0.756315385,-0.023326734
    BZPKZ2934L,0.428421095,0.792023892,0.064818298
    EGIPR1094A,0.350242033,0.598746704,0.101737362
    PQTFK6203U,0.383561916,0.660697282,0.10642655
    UYLGX7811M,0.509668823,1.037205877,-0.017868231
    ICEHA2251J,0.643924109,1.452395674,-0.164547457
\end{filecontents*}
```

Comment: To pre-suppose a comment, I know how to use R's `tikzDevice` package and would rather avoid that approach applied to the above R package for dot-whisker plots. I want to plot directly in PGFplots based on coefficient estimate and standard error.

Comment: I have no reason to prefer using the box whisker package in PGF. If it is easier to do in a scalable manner without box and whisker, please suggest an approach. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks fo adding the code! My main problem is that I am not really very firm in the backgrounds of this (even though I probably should) but if your question is if one could read out the values `0.55`, `0.70` and `0.85` (or `0.55` and `0.15` for symmetric whiskers) from a csv file to create a series of  `\addplot+ [
boxplot prepared={
lower whisker=0.55, 
% lower quartile=,
median=0.70,
% upper quartile=, 
upper whisker=0.85,
},
] 
coordinates {};` which use these values, the answer is of course affirmative.

Comment: Yes that would be what I am after as a *start*. Read a `.csv` where each row is a separate group, and there are four columns 1. group name 2. "median" 3. "upper whisker" 4. "lower whisker". I use quotations as this is *not* what is being represented statistically, but it is how we would interpret in terms of the box and whisker plot semantics. However, I say this is a *start* because I'd then be unsatisfied with the vertical line representations which are more confusing than having dots, see `R` `dotwhisker` package. Hence an alternative to the box whisker package in PGF might be more viable.

Comment: Can you provide a sketch of how these "whiskers" should look like?

Comment: I have added an example to my question. I think stylistically the best outcome is halfway between the R example and my MWE. There should be a dot or vertical line for the midpoint and very short vertical lines at the end of the whiskers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a code that goes through a csv file and adds these "whiskers". The dimensions of the vertical lines are determined by `/pgfplots/boxplot/box extend=0.1` (and `/pgfplots/boxplot/whisker extend`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikzlings}%<- for the second part of the answer ;-)
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}%<- for the second part of the answer
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{whiskers.dat}
0.6 0.35 0.85
0.7 0.55 0.85
0.9 0.85 0.95
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\newcounter{iloop}
\newcommand*{\ReadOutElement}[4]{%
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{#2}{[index]#3}\of{#1}%
    \let#4\pgfplotsretval
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread[header=false]{whiskers.dat}{\datatable}   
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatable}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\numrows}{\pgfplotsretval}
\setcounter{iloop}{1}
\edef\MyLabels{Group A}
\loop\stepcounter{iloop}\edef\MyLabels{\MyLabels,Group \Alph{iloop}}%
\ifnum\value{iloop}<\numrows\repeat
\begin{axis}[
    ytick={1,...,\numrows},
    yticklabels/.expanded=\MyLabels,
    /pgfplots/boxplot/box extend=0.1,
    /pgfplots/boxplot/whisker extend=%
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/boxplot/box extend}*4,
    ]
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,\the\numexpr\numrows-1}
{
\ReadOutElement{\datatable}{#1}{0}{\Median}
\ReadOutElement{\datatable}{#1}{1}{\Upper}
\ReadOutElement{\datatable}{#1}{2}{\Lower}
\edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot+ [mark=*,
boxplot prepared={
lower whisker=\Lower, 
% lower quartile=,
median=\Median,
% upper quartile=, 
upper whisker=\Upper,
},
] coordinates {(#1+1,\Median)};
}
\temp
}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\bigskip\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
\marmot[whiskers,teeth]
\node[ellipse callout, fill=white,
    draw,
 font=\sffamily,align=center,%inner sep=-2pt,
 callout relative pointer={(-150:0.9)}] at (2,2.4) {How about\\ my whiskers?};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Your larger data file works, too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{dotwhisker.csv}
    group,point_est,upper,lower
    RAMOF4414X,0.25858685,0.878367526,-0.161193826
    DOYDL6809E,0.555485848,1.400010767,-0.089039071
    YHYYL9849M,0.716888235,1.368127463,0.265649007
    JMQIG4509E,0.030860459,0.453325401,-0.191604482
    SQYRJ4202T,0.585824938,1.206768474,0.164881402
    OYSCJ0457U,0.601211178,1.362723257,0.0396991
    ZQAXZ5423I,0.385052008,0.892098437,0.078005579
    MDWEF7504F,0.390673629,1.063439815,-0.082092558
    IJUSO8696V,0.3871096,1.084017824,-0.109798624
    BQSBP8990Q,0.321992434,0.908002585,-0.064017717
    OCDWZ7363Q,0.40456146,0.981590932,0.027531988
    OHEEJ6147W,0.300322711,0.814591182,-0.01394576
    KCRLD3716J,0.344749221,0.875554365,0.013944077
    MFPJM1799W,0.512891763,1.177304879,0.048478648
    DIPEZ2121T,0.691898812,1.505729535,0.078068088
    LYOUI9349J,0.477942901,1.060060156,0.095825646
    VZFYT9091T,0.397798099,0.863976498,0.1316197
    OEQZM1870D,0.317760917,0.817961252,0.017560582
    VTGHR8934O,0.332565664,0.913827561,-0.048696233
    KMCVQ3734I,0.983167036,1.675403499,0.490930572
    ZALVK0344T,0.526817644,1.122164944,0.131470344
    PNXOL7981C,0.401862821,0.962308107,0.041417534
    PYIND4089E,0.411890426,0.88306747,0.140713381
    PNZTF5825U,0.591917888,1.201046391,0.182789386
    LPPRP3997H,0.361255951,1.008833148,-0.086321247
    VBUVF6797C,0.210359018,0.815565496,-0.194847461
    INHXV3841Z,0.614951144,1.31681457,0.113087718
    RPWRJ7560V,0.295268855,0.810041955,-0.019504244
    SCTCT3620G,0.49697234,1.070902402,0.123042278
    MAYYI9754J,0.31281028,0.774220754,0.051399806
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\newcounter{iloop}
\newcommand*{\ReadOutElement}[4]{%
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{#2}{[index]#3}\of{#1}%
    \let#4\pgfplotsretval
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread[header=true,col sep=comma]{dotwhisker.csv}{\datatable}   
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatable}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\numrows}{\pgfplotsretval}
\ReadOutElement{\datatable}{0}{0}{\Label}
\edef\MyLabels{\Label}
\setcounter{iloop}{1}
\loop
\ReadOutElement{\datatable}{\number\value{iloop}}{0}{\Label}%
\edef\MyLabels{\MyLabels,\Label}%
\stepcounter{iloop}%
\ifnum\value{iloop}<\numrows\repeat
\begin{axis}[width=12cm,height=14cm,
    ytick={1,...,\numrows},
    yticklabels/.expanded=\MyLabels,
    /pgfplots/boxplot/box extend=0.1,
    /pgfplots/boxplot/whisker extend=%
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/boxplot/box extend}*4,
    ]
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,\the\numexpr\numrows-1}
{
\ReadOutElement{\datatable}{#1}{1}{\Median}
\ReadOutElement{\datatable}{#1}{2}{\Upper}
\ReadOutElement{\datatable}{#1}{3}{\Lower}
\edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot+ [mark=*,
boxplot prepared={
lower whisker=\Lower, 
% lower quartile=,
median=\Median,
% upper quartile=, 
upper whisker=\Upper,
},
] coordinates {(#1+1,\Median)};
}
\temp
}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I updated an earlier `dotwhisker.csv` I provided to be symmetric contemporaneously to @Schrödinger'scat excellent answer which uses the original `.csv`. This answer works well regardless, except for automatically recognizing group names. Thanks.

Comment: Marmot is back! :)

Comment: Yes. I just generated those strings randomly as names along with generating the numerical data randomly. I wanted to emphasize that it might not be as simple as looping over a numeric or alphabetic counter such as 'group A', 'group B' etc. My MWE was misleading in this sense. Of course, instead of random strings I could have put cities, countries, species or some other large categorial variable.

Comment: @Sav-econ The labels are in.

Comment: @CarLaTeX YAY!!